# javascript type error "is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, constructor, requirejs

I have several classes for representing different types of tables. I put names of classes to the dictionary. I take class name from the dictionary by key and try to create instance of class by using construction "new var_with_class_name()" but get an error "TypeError: dictionary[model_name] is not a constructor". 
This code is packed as require.js module. 
Code:

```
define("models", ["jquery", "ui"], function($, ui){

var TimeTableRow = function()
{ /* class methods definitions */ }
var WayTableRow = function()
{ /* ... */ }
var ModelsDictionary = function()
{
   var self = this;
   self.getModel = function(model_name)
   {
      var dictionary = {'time':"TimeTableRow", 'way':"WayTableRow"};
      return new dictionary[model_name]();
   }
}
return new ModelsDictionary();
});
```

Example of usage from another require.js module (I skip all requirejs configs and imports, just line of code that throws described error):
    `var tableRow = models.getModel(item_type);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
 var dictionary = {'time':"TimeTableRow", 'way':"WayTableRow"};
 return new dictionary[model_name]();
```

`dictionary[model_name]` evaluates to a *string* (or undefined) and `new ("x")()` is nonsense. Instead, the lookup should evaluate to the *actual* constructor functions:

```
 var dictionary = {'time': TimeTableRow, 'way': WayTableRow};
 return new dictionary[model_name]();
```

Remember that functions are just objects in JavaScript.